# Checking if current context is jQuery stack

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example i need to check if current context is jQuery stack. How would you do it? Ignoring methods checking. It's ugly solution. :)

For example:

```
if(it_is_jquery_stack_context) {
// do some stuff with jQuery support
}
else {
// do some  stuff without it
}
```

**UPDATE**

For example:

```
if(typeof this.get=='function' && this.length && this.get(0)===dom_ element) { 
   // do some stuff
}
```

The last question is:

How to check if `this.get(0)` is instance of dom element?

Comment: You mean checking if jQuery exists? If `this` is a jQuery object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really just guessing your problem here but if you mean to check if `this` refers to an jQuery object you can do:

```
if( "jquery" in this ) { //lowercase intended
// do some stuff with jQuery support
}
else {
// do some  stuff without it
}
```

note that by jQuery object I mean a jQuery object, not the jQuery namespace.. as in `"jquery" in jQuery` is false but `"jquery" in jQuery("div")` is true.

> The last question is:
>
> How to check if this.get(0) is instance of dom element?

For example:

```
this[0] && this[0].nodeType && this[0].nodeType === 1
```

But this is useless as jQuery objects don't always have dom nodes in them.

Comment: A bit closer. But if custom context is object with jquery property or method, the statement will go wrong. Better would be checking like that if(typeof this.get=='function' && this.length && this.get(0)==dom_ element) { do some stuff } . But i don't know to check if property is an DOM element.

Comment: adding a lowercased jquery property to an object manually is comparable to this code `jQuery = null; $ = null;` so you should be safe with this :) Just for fun you could do stuff like `this.constructor === jQuery` but it won't work if one object is from another iframe for example.

Comment: this.constructor === jQuery guess that will do for a while. :) , but better would be checking instanceof DOM element. Thanks btw ;)

Comment: Ho-ho-ho!I knew jQuery should have something like that. :) Here it is! http://api.jquery.com/context/ The question is closed.

Comment: It's safer to check for jQuery rather than check if it's an element, when checking an element, especially with `instanceof`, all bets are off

Comment: Yea true, instanceof jQuery will do as well i think

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to check `this` to see if it's a jQuery object:

```
if (this.jquery)
{
    //this is a jquery object so you can act accordingly
}
else
{
    //this is not a jQuery object, you can do $(this) to make it into one if it's a DOM object
}
```

Comment: And what if custom context already have this.jquery property, but it's not an jQuery stack?

Comment: Well then you'd have to come up with a different way to achieve this :-) Based on the information provided, this will be an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following:

```js
if (jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
}
```

**OR**

```js
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```

Comment: You are checking global context mate. Updated my question a bit.

Comment: The first will not work. If `jQuery` is not loaded, an error would be thrown